# How can I get String from Any in swift3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

Such as I get a `dic` from `fetchData`:

```
(lldb) po dic

▿ 3 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "total"
    - .1 : 0.00
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "year"
    - .1 : 2016
  ▿ 2 : 2 elements
    - .0 : "month"
    - .1 : 12

(lldb) po dic["year"]
▿ Optional<Any>


(lldb) po dic["year"]!
2016
```

Is there a function to get `String` form `Any`?

The function's usage is like below:

```
let total = UtilSwift.getStrFromAny(dic["total"] as Any )
```

In `objective-c`, I written a method:

```
+ (NSString*)getStringWithoutNull:(id)value
{
    NSString *strValue = @"";
   if(value != nil){
        strValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", value];
    }

    if([strValue isEqualToString:@"null"])
    {
        return @"";
    }

    if ([strValue isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

        return @"";
    }

    return strValue;
}
```

Is in `swift` could write a method like this to get `String` form `Any`?

---

The `Any` maybe `Int`, `String`, `""`, `Double`, or other type.

---

**EDIT - 1**

After the tried in `Playground`. :

```
import UIKit

let dict:[String:Any]  = ["aa": 123, "year":1994, "month":"12"]

let string = String(describing:dict["year"]) ?? ""   // Try to turn result into a String, o

print(string)  // If I print(string!), and there will report error.
```

The warning:

[image: the test]

---

**EDIT 2**

I know the `edit -2` maybe paint the lily, but if when use the `func` below, when I deliver a `Opitional` value to the `func`, the return String will be `Opitinal` too, how to avoid that?

This below is my test in `Playground`, `dic["b"] as Any` convert the parameter to `Opitional`:

```
   let dic:[String:Any] = [  // ["b": 12, "A": "A"]

    "A":"A",
    "b":12
]

func stringFromAny(_ value:Any?) -> String {

    if let nonNil = value, !(nonNil is NSNull) {

        return String(describing: nonNil) // "Optional(12)"
    }
    return ""
}

let str = stringFromAny(dic["b"] as Any)  // "Optional(12)"
```

Comment: @Daniel Hall. Your answer is good, I know how to deal with the  unwritten law requirement of mine now, so I changed that. and I think put that unreasonable requirement in there is no use for others have the problem, when they see the question here.

Comment: You shouldn't be casting dic["b"] as Any.  Just change your last line to be:  `let str = stringFromAny(dic["b"])`. The function already accepts a parameter of `Any?`, which is the return type for dictionary[key].

Comment: @Daniel Hall I know it is paint the lily, but if user deliver a `Opitinal value` to the `func`, we can not avoid user's behavior, I think the `Tool` class's `func` must be rigorous for use.

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the ambiguity in Swift between `Any` and `Any?`, it's more complex to work around this case than you would suspect.  I don't personally think the code should compensate for a developer explicitly forcing an `Any?` value to be considered as an `Any` when it's not accurate or needed.  But I did update my answer with a version of the code that will detect and handle that sort of case, as well as other double-optional type inputs.

Comment: @Daniel Hall, your sprit is my example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this one:

```
func stringFromAny(_ value:Any?) -> String {
    if let nonNil = value, !(nonNil is NSNull) {
        return String(describing: nonNil)
    }
    return ""
}
```

Update:

If the calling code invokes the above function with an `Any?` parameter that is explicitly cast to `Any` (a strange scenario which the Swift 3 compiler allows), then it will consider the final type of the parameter to be a non-optional optional, i.e. an `Any` value where the type `Any` represents is `Any?`. Or, in other terms, the value would be considered to be `Optional<Any>.some(value:Any?)`.

In this case, the `if let` to unwrap the "some" case returns an optional value as the result in the function implementation.  Which means that the final string description will include the "Optional" designation.

Because of the various oddities around the fact that the Swift 3 compiler will happily cast between `Any` and `Any?` and consider a value of type `Any` to be a value of type `Any?` and vice versa, it's actually pretty complicated to detect if an `Any` really contains an `Any?' or not, and to unwrap accordingly.

A version of this same function, along with some necessary additional extensions is provided below. This version will recursively flatten an `Any` value containing any number of nested `Any?` cases inside to retrieve the innermost non-optional value.

While this is what you seem to be looking for, I am of the opinion that it's a lot of hassle to work around something a programmer should not be doing anyway, namely miscasting a known `Any?` value to be `Any` because the compiler has a weird exception for that, even when it is not actually true.

Here's the "developer-proof" version of the code:

```
protocol OptionalType {
    var unsafelyUnwrapped: Any { get }
    var unsafelyFlattened: Any { get }
}

extension Optional: OptionalType {
    var unsafelyUnwrapped: Any { return self.unsafelyUnwrapped }
    var unsafelyFlattened: Any { return (self.unsafelyUnwrapped as? OptionalType)?.unsafelyFlattened ?? self.unsafelyUnwrapped }
}

func stringFromAny(_ value:Any?) -> String {
    switch value {
    case .some(let wrapped):
        if let notNil =  wrapped as? OptionalType, !(notNil.unsafelyFlattened is NSNull) {
            return String(describing: notNil.unsafelyFlattened)
        } else if !(wrapped is OptionalType) {
            return String(describing: wrapped)
        }
        return ""
    case .none :
        return ""
    }
}
```

Comment: The question is asking how to turn "any" data type into a string. The Objective-C code accepts any "JSON object" and returns a string.

Comment: @Daniel Hall , I mean if the `value` no matter is `Int`, `Double`, `String`, `nil` I want to convert to `String`, Such as `3.00`, `3`, `"3"` I all want to convert to `String`.

Comment: @Daniel Hall, I think you can let the answer better, see my edit.

Comment: @Daniel Hall, I tested the answer, but find the return `str` maybe `Opitional`, that is not my want, how can I get the `non-opitional` value?

Comment: @aircraft That's odd... in what case are you seeing an optional?  The function returns a non-optional `String`, so you should never be getting an optional back from it.  Do you have an example?

Comment: @Daniel Hall, I have tested, find the  parameter `_ value` , if is ` Opitinal`, the return `String` is `Optional`. Could I avoid this?

Comment: @aircraft  I think you aren't getting an Optional<String> result, but rather seeing a non-optional string that consists of the description "Optional(something)". This could happen if you are passing in a _double optional_ parameter, e.g. a `String??`.  The compiler should warn you if that is the case, but you could resolve this by flattening your double optional parameter back into a single optional, like this:  `print(stringFromAny(yourParameter ?? nil))`

Comment: @Daniel Hall , thanks your patient for the question, I do this did not get a warning and I test this in my `playgroud`, the detail you can see my `EDIT - 2`. So I think the answer my be more better.

Comment: @aircraft  Ah, thanks for posting the example in your question.  The issue is caused by explicitly casting `dict["b"]` to `Any`. Accessing the value for a key on a dictionary returns `Any?` (because it might be nil) so it shouldn't be cast to the non-optional `Any`.  And the function actually deals with an optional `Any?` parameter just fine.  So change your last line to be: `let str = stringFromAny(dic["b"])` and I think it will be just what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Use `!` if the value is an optional

```
String(describing: nonNil)  // "Optional(12)"
String(describing: nonNil!) // "12"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing a similar issue with the `change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey: Any]?` paramater in the `observeValue` function.

Here is how I get String from the Any value:

```
let urlValue = change?[.newKey]
let url = String(describing: urlValue!) // Unwrap urlValue here to prevent optional String
print(url) // This is now a String
```

Comment: This will crash if `change` is nil or if there is no value for `.newKey`. Use `if let` to properly handle optional values.

Comment: @HangarRash If you would just experiment or read up on how [observeValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1416553-observevalue) works instead of downvoting me.  `change` being nil is possible but unlikely (which is why it's declared an optional), and no value for `.newKey` is not possible due to the nature of how this callback works.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that the `change` parameter can be `nil` and the value for `.newKey` may not exist. It can only be there if `.new` is passed as an option when calling `addObserver` so stating that it's not possible for the value to not exist isn't true. It's always best to code for optionals safely and avoid needless use of forced-unwrapping if it's possible for it to cause a crash. And lastly, you would want to cast `change?[.newKey]` to a specific type, not leave it as `Any?` and then force-convert it to a `String`.

Comment: @HangarRash Ok you have a point on the nil safety check, and it's great you are aware as everyone should. I wasn't too strict on that, because the goal is to answer the original question (How to get String from Any in swift3). So, to elaborate, you can't simply cast `change?[.newKey]` to a specific type because you will get nil. Xcode doesn't read `change?[.newKey]` as an optional because it isn't, but the value you get from `change?[.newKey]` is the optional. Hence, I'm demonstrating in my answer that this value is to be unwrapped so you won't see the weird `optional()` tag.