# How to remove Optional from String Value Swift

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'd like to use a String value without the optional extension. I parse this data from firebase using the following code:

```
Database.database().reference(withPath:
    "Locations").child("Cities").observe(.value, with: { (snapShot) in
        if snapShot.exists() {
            let array:NSArray = snapShot.children.allObjects as NSArray

            for child in array {
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot

                let cityName = snap.key
                let cityNameString = "\(cityName)"
                if snap.value is NSDictionary {
                    let data:NSDictionary = snap.value as! NSDictionary
                    let lat = data.value(forKey: "lat")
                    let lng = data.value(forKey: "lng")
                    let radius = data.value(forKey: "radius")
                    let latstring = "\(lat)"
                    let lngstring = "\(lng)" 
                    let radiusstring = "\(radius)" 

                    let city = CityObject(name: cityNameString , lat: latstring , lng: lngstring, radius: radiusstring)
                    print("Value is", laststring)  
                    self.selectCity(cityObject: city)
                }                            

            }
        }
    })
```

after parsing this data i try to print e.g. the latstring and get following outpup:

> Value is Optional(52.523553)

my CityObject looks like the following:

```
class CityObject{
var name: String?
var lat: String?
var lng: String?
var radius: String?

init(name: String?, lat: String?, lng: String?, radius: String?){
    self.name = name
    self.lat = lat
    self.lng = lng
    self.radius = radius
}
```

Comment: Do you mean that you just want to print `52.523553` by itself? You need to be more explicit and clear about what's wrong, and what your ideal output would be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an optional value in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003642/what-is-an-optional-value-in-swift)

Comment: I suggest reading the free book on Swift from Apple. You can download it for free and it covers all the basics like Optionals. Voting to close this as a duplicate question.

Comment: Check out my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75712608/4261600)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like @GioR said, the value is Optional(52.523553) because the type of latstring is implicitly: String?. This is due to the fact that
    let lat = data.value(forKey: "lat")
will return a String? which implicitly sets the type for lat.
see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1412591-value
for the documentation on value(forKey:)

Swift has a number of ways of handling nil. The three that may help you are,
The nil coalescing operator:

```
??
```

This operator gives a default value if the optional turns out to be nil:

```
let lat: String = data.value(forKey: "lat") ?? "the lat in the dictionary was nil!"
```

the guard statement

```
guard let lat: String = data.value(forKey: "lat") as? String else {
    //Oops, didn't get a string, leave the function!
}
```

the guard statement lets you turn an optional into it's non-optional equivalent, or you can exit the function if it happens to be nil

the if let

```
if let lat: String = data.value(forKey: "lat") as? String {
    //Do something with the non-optional lat
}
//Carry on with the rest of the function
```

Hope this helps ^^

Comment: Nitpicking Its `nil coalescing` operator not `nill coalescing` :). **Important:** it will check the `nil` value not `null`.  `Null` is not `nil` actually.

Comment: @TheTiger Thanks for the nitpicks! That's how people improve ^^. Also, I was thinking that because pure Swift doesn't really have Null, it wouldn't matter with the intent being similar. After seeing your comment however, I did some research and those distinctions would indeed be very important especially if there is a mixture of Swift and Objective-C. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

`Optional` is because you're printing an optional value `?`.

`print("Value is", laststring!)`

Above code will not print `Optional`. But avoid forcecasting  and use `guard` for safety.

```
guard let value = lastString else {return}
print("Value is", value)
```

Or you can use [Nil Coalescing](https://www.google.co.in/search?client=firefox-b-ab&dcr=0&biw=1894&bih=923&ei=5vXWWrHXOIzWvgSVpZzwCw&q=Nil+Coalescing&oq=Nil+Coalescing&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i67k1l2j0i20i263k1j0l4.21574.21574.0.22484.1.1.0.0.0.0.318.318.3-1.1.0.foo%2Ccfro%3D1%2Ckpnr%3D200...0...1.2.64.psy-ab..0.1.318....0.Vfd0wNRFudU) operator.

```
print("Value is", laststring ?? "yourDefaultString")
```

So in case `laststring` is `nil` it will print `yourDefaultString`.

Important message for you, Use `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`, use `Array` instead of `NSArray` this is `swift`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your value is actually an optional. You could either do

```
if let myString = laststring {
    print("Value is ", myString)
}
```

or provide a default value like so

```
print("Value is ", laststring ?? "")
```

(in this case the provided default value is "")